# jScrollpane jquery plugin reducing the scrolling area of the vertical side scroller

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, jscrollpane

I'm using jScrollPane via the HTML5Player from Tean.

Here's my problem:

when  I add borders (3px solid black) to the playlistitem element, (these are li's in a ul),
JScrollpane works correctly but it shortens the dynamically generated vertical scroll bar,

So that even though it scrolls the content correctly, 
it shortens the scroll bar area by about half the size and the bottom part of the scroll bar turns red.

I fixed the red part by specifying black or transparent, but it looks like the scroll bar only goes down halfway, but yet the content scrolls correctly.

I was unable to override the css and define a specific pixel amount (I did, but it didn't fix the problem.)

So it means that the plugin is commandeering my efforts and dynamically generating the height, which is now in error because I added the borders. So it looks like it's not adding the border amount when it calculates how tall to make the scroll bar area.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is quite a puzzler.